# question mark while trying to get user's Facebook profile picture in Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

for my android application which use Parse as backend, i've integrated a facebook login. So for now, i get user's name and facebook profile id since it's all i need. 
For retrieving his profile picture i'm using those simple lines:

```
Long hash = mUser.getLong(ParseConstants.KEY_FACEBOOK_ID); 

String gravatarUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + hash +
                                "/picture?width=120&height=120";

                        Picasso.with(getBaseContext())
                                .load(gravatarUrl)
                                .placeholder(R.color.focused_green_button)
                                .into(imgSingle);
```

when i was testing the app it worked well for 3 facebook account, but now i'm sending the app in beta version in google play, it's always returning a question mark. 
I also don't understand why the same url works for some profiles and doesn't for others.
As an example, this one works, i can see the profile picture:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/868281133254730/picture?width=120&height=120
```

and this one doesn't:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/10207266268160228/picture?width=120&height=120
```

:/
Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

resolved !
It was all about the user Id. When signing up by facebook i was registering the facebook id of the new user in a colomn (type=Long) by something like : 
currentUser.put(ParseConstants.KEY_FB_ID, jsonObject.getLong(ParseConstants.KEY_ID));
the thing is that there is an issue with using getLong in json when the number is quite big which is the case with facebook ids. So what i did now is retrieving it as a string! Hope that it would help someone